# multiple include files in apache virtualhost

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, virtualhost, serveralias

I have a pile of domains and my customer wants www also available.

I made two text files. 
One that starts with ServerAlias and the domain names
and another text file that starts with ServerAlias and the www domain names.

Each text file is one long line.

Did a configtest syntax check, apache says OK
Did -t Dump virtual hosts command and all the aliases are loaded in correctly.

In the browser can't access any www.domains.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sale.com
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/sale.com-domainlist.txt
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/sale.com-domainlistwww.txt
DocumentRoot /var/www/sale.com
<Directory /var/www/sale.com>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The include files

domainlist.txt

```
ServerAlias sale1.com sale2.com fail.com
```

domainlistwww.txt

```
ServerAlias www.sale1.com www.sal2.com www.fail2.com
```

Partial vhost dump file from server

```
(/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost sale.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sale.com.conf:1)
             alias sale1.com
             alias sale2.com
             alias fail.com
             alias fail2.com
             alias www.sale1.com
             alias www.sale2.com
             alias www.fail.com
             alias www.fail2.com
port 80 namevhost mypersonalwebsite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mypersonalwebsite.com.conf:2)
             alias www.mypersonalwebsite.com
```

Comment: Show us the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sale.com-domainlist.txt` contents (and the other one too) or at least one domain's worth of a snippet.  you don't need any include files for this, much less two of them...

Comment: Each list has 2000 domains in it pointing to the same folder.

Comment: Do the www domains hit your default virtual host, or is something else happening?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: can't access the www domains from web browser

Comment: That's too vague. Please tell us exactly what is happening.

Comment: One of the real domains is http://sale900.com the browser shows it my customer wants people to be able to go to http://www.sale900.com this is not connecting in the browser. Same issue for the other 1999 domains,

Comment: I dont know if its a server misconfiguration issue or a dns issue on their end, there are cname records for www pointing to the proper a record for each domain

Comment: Your DNS is not working for `www.sale900.com`

Comment: thanks, I will let my customer know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sale.com
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/sale.com-domainlist.txt
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/sale.com-domainlistwww.txt
DocumentRoot /var/www/sale.com
<Directory /var/www/sale.com>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above configuration works fine for multiple include files.

Each include file starts with ServerAlias and all the domains should be only separated by a space.

My client's DNS settings didn't accommodate for www. which is a subdomain. We used an A record for wildcard domains in the dns settings of their registrar.
example:

`* IN 45.65.35.76`

`NAME *
VALUE 45.65.36.76`

The asterisk apparently lets you have multiple subdomains without having to make a separate CNAME entry for each.